# Mobile responsive stylesheet works on its own, but not within the parent stylesheet

Tags: html, css, mobile

As the title says, I have two stylesheets, one for mobile, the other for desktop.
I am combining both by using the `@media screen and (max-width: 1007) {}` query.

This however doesn't seem to function properly for me, as some elements don't get affected by the stylesheet - the desktop stylesheet is overriding some of the elements but not **all**, for some reason.

Is it bad practice to combine stylesheets? Should I have separate links to them in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

**My recommendation:**

I would have two separate CSS files in your `<head>` like so.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive-styles.css">
```

Otherwise, you can combine them by having only one `main.css`: This would look like so:

```HTML
@import url("style.css");
@import url("css/responsive.css");
@import url("css/custom.css");
@import url("css/fonts.css");
@import url("css/jquery-ui.css");
```

The end goal with this is to have only one `.main` CSS file which includes all your main styles, responsive styles, fonts, etc.

The result would consist of **only** this in your `<head>`

```html
<link href="main.css" rel=stylesheet>
```

Keep in mind stylesheets are loaded in parallel and the page does not block further parsing waiting for a stylesheet to load. Hence, my recommendation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have? Mobile and Desktop is combined in one stylesheet. My ```@media``` query is at the very bottom, so that the styles on top take priority as well.